# Export DIV to PDF don't work in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf

I have a div with tables and graphs and need export to PDF, I used html2canvas.js to create one canvas and use jsPDF.js to add the canvas in the pdf document and it worked! but only in Mozilla Fire Fox and Google Chrome, Internet Explorer 9 , 10 and 11 did not work! Anyone know if it is possible to do this in IE or is an incompatibility problem?

CODE:

function createPDF(relatorio){

//get the Report chice
 var form = $(relatorio);

```
 var cache_width = form.width();

//A4 SIZE
 var a4  =[ 595.28,  841.89];  

 //CALL THE GET CANVAS FUNCTION
 getCanvas(form).then(function(canvas){

     var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

     var imgWidth = 210; 

     var pageHeight = 295;  

     var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;

     var heightLeft = imgHeight;

     var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');

     var position = 0;

     doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);

     heightLeft -= pageHeight;

     while (heightLeft >= 0) {

       position = heightLeft - imgHeight;

       doc.addPage();

       doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);

       heightLeft -= pageHeight;

     }

     doc.save('relatorioOrcadoRealizado.pdf');
     form.width(cache_width);
```

}

//CONVERT DIV FOR CANVAS

function getCanvas(form){

return html2canvas(form,{

```
 imageTimeout:2000,

 removeContainer:true

});
```

}

Comment: Welcome to the world of web development.  IE will usually cause all your issues and be very difficult to work around.  Your task should work in IE 10 and 11, but will never work in IE 9.  You should check to see if your sight is running in compatibility mode, if it is turn that off and you should be able to run your task in 10 and 11

Comment: thaks for you response! i do and work to IE 10 and 11, you know samehow i can make this work to IE 9?

Comment: Does your library officially support IE 9, they would be your best resource for determining if it is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after same years of search, i have found a solution for this problem, i need to use [polyfill](https://github.com/inexorabletash/polyfill) to supply the miss of an arrayBuffer in IE9.